# How can i change the system wide default graphical text editor?

Tags: linux, crunchbang

As with #! waldorf, geany is the default graphical text editor. However i want to substitute that with sublime text. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have it installed through apt-get?

If not, add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
```

and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/sublime-text-2-ubuntu-ppa.html))

You can then set it as default with xdg-mime if you know the mime types corresponding to the file extensions. For example, to open all `.txt` files in Sublime Text, run this in terminal:

```
xdg-mime default sublime-text-2.desktop text/plain
```

To make this work in case you're opening the text file inside some KDE program like `Dolphin` or `Konqueror` you will have to copy the corresponding lines under `[Default Applications]` in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and paste them under `[Added Associations]` in the same file. So your `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` would look like this if you had only this one `.txt` associaton:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=sublime-text-2.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/plain=sublime-text-2.desktop
```